# Testing if a string contains one of several thousand substrings

Tags: regex, string, language-agnostic, substring

I'm going to be running through live twitter data and attempting to pull out tweets that mention, for example, movie titles. Assuming I have a list of ~7000 hard-coded movie titles I'd  like to look against, what's the best way to select the relevant tweets? This project is in it's infancy so I'm open to any looking into any solution (i.e. language agnostic.) Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:** I'd be curious if anyone had any insight to how the Yahoo! Placemaker API, solves this problem. It can take a text string and return a geocoded JSON result of all the locations mentioned in it.

Comment: Do you have that data somewhere at your disposal or you are going to use Twitter Search API? As far as I know, Search API only lets you run simple and short queries like "Movie1 OR Movie2"

Comment: @MichaelM. I'm using the Search API because in addition to containing a title, the tweets need to be in a given format (e.g. "[string1] is the better than [string2]".) I'll be searching for "is better than" but have to find a way if string1 contains one of the things I care about.

Comment: Argh, I read hard-core movies at first^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try Wu and Manber's [A Fast Algorithm For Multi-Pattern Searching](http://webglimpse.net/pubs/TR94-17.pdf).

The multi-pattern matching problem lies at the heart of virus scanning, so you might look to scanner implementations for inspiration.  [ClamAV](http://www.clamav.net/lang/en/download/sources/), for example, is open source and some papers have been published describing its algorithms:

Lin, Lin and Lai: [A Hybrid Algorithm of Backward Hashing and Automaton Tracking for Virus Scanning](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpl/freeabs_all.jsp?arnumber=5453354) (a variant of Wu-Manber; the paper is behind the IEEE paywall).

Cha, Moraru, et al: [SplitScreen: Enabling Efﬁcient, Distributed Malware Detection](http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~jiyongj/papers/nsdi10.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

If you use **compiled** regular expressions, it should be pretty fast.  Maybe especially if you put lots of titles in one expression.

Comment: Depends on the regex library - you'll want one based on DFAs, not backtracking. re2c or google's re2 should work well. But WReach suggests an algorithm that may be even faster (although I don't think it'd make much difference if the strings to match are short)

Answer (score 2):

Efficiently searching for many terms in a long character sequence would require a specialized algorithm to avoid testing for every term at every position.

But since it sounds like you have short strings with a known pattern, you should be able to use something fairly simple. Store the set of titles you care about in a hash table or tree. Parse out "string1" and "string2" from each tweet using a regex, and test whether they are contained in the set.

Comment: This could be slightly complicated by, using the previous example, cases where string1 is preceded by some pablum like "I think that..." which would get included when the tweet was broke into its components. Trying merely the last word before the "is better than" would also break on multi-word titles

Answer (score 0):

Working off what erickson suggested, the most feasible search is for the ("is better than" in your example), then checking for one of the 7,000 terms. You could instead narrow the set by creating 7,000 searches for "[movie] is better than" and then filtering manually on the second movie, but you'll probably hit the [search rate limit](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting) pretty quickly.

You could speed up the searching by using a dedicated search service like Solr instead of using text parsing. You might be able to pull out titles quickly using some natural language processing service ([OpenCalais](http://www.opencalais.com/)?), but that would be better suited to batch processing.

Answer (score 0):

For simultaneously searching for a large number of possible targets, the [Rabin-Karp algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin%E2%80%93Karp_string_search_algorithm) can often be useful.